# Nesting Raphael's sets in Raphael sets for Raphael javascript library

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I've been trying to nest sets within sets but to no avail.

This concept comes from, photoshop, where you can group elements into a folder/set, and nest them into another folder/set.

I'm trying to combine two or more sets into one easily, so I don't have to manually take everything apart to integrate the code again.

This step is to make way for collective behavior control of the set, e.g. mouse hovers, clicks, translations, and transformations.

Has anyone experience this and found a workaround of sorts to this problem please?
Any help to tackle this issue is appreciated.

To elaborate, here's some contrived example code of what I'm trying to do:

```
var r = Raphael("holder");
r.height = 400
r.width = 300

var buttons = r.set();
var target_objects = r.set();

buttons.push(
    r.rect(0,0,r.width/10,r.height/10).attr({fill:"#000"})
);

target_objects.push(
    r.rect(50,50,r.width/5,r.height/5).attr({fill:"#0F0"})
);

var super_set = r.set();

# Trying to combine sets. Note: this of course doesn't work
super_set.push(buttons,target_objects);

super_set.mouseover(function(){
    alert();
});
```

Comment: What do you mean? Set could be nested into another set without problems. Show the code that doesn’t work.

Comment: I've looked into the Raphael reference page, as well as scoured the web for similar issues for a workaround. No one seems to have an answer, or I'm not good at searching for references. I've edited the question to include an example code about what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: Even if your code worked, you wouldn't create nested sets. Do you want nested sets, or do you want to splice two sets into one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Dmitry points out, sets can be pushed into other sets, so your code should work. **[Try it out with this jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aJYn3/)**.

Comment: “The items cannot be other sets” No they can be other sets. This is the whole point!

Comment: @Dmitry - You're right. I thought I tried it before, guess not. Wish the documentation made some reference to this.